# PKCS file system in Android

Tags: android, cryptography, nfc, apdu, hce

I would like to create an android application. In this application I would like to create a PKCS file system (like in Java Card applet) (not involving secure element) and perform cryptographic operations through APDU commands. Is it possible? Any valuable suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "PKCS file system"? Individual files in some PKCS#<number> formats?

Comment: All files needed to perform cryptography. see the link. ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/pervasive/info/BlueZ-PKCS15.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although APDU's are meant to be send over a T=0 or T=1 transmission protocol. You may map those on the internet protocol, but some mapping may be required.

You could start with [JCardSim](http://jcardsim.org/) which implements the Java Card specifications (in part) on the JRE. It will likely also run on Android, although you may have to make some modifications.

Comment: Thanks Owlstead for your quick reply. Is the JCardSim support Extended length Apdu? I like to send Apdu commands by using androids Host card emulation. I can not find any information about Support of JCardSim in android platform.

Can you help me to know  how can i implement jCardSim in android platform to support host card emulation. Please send some helpful information/links if available.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried it on Android yet, but as said, basically it is a pure Java implementation. Same for extended length, I would have to look it up (note that it is open source, so just look up all references to `ExtendedLength` interface, and you should find if it is supported or not).

Comment: How can i get "javax.smartcardio" library on Android?

Comment: Thanks again owlstead for your support. I have installed rt.jar from JRE but after running my android application shows "Could not find class 'javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU' etc. Is it the right JAR file that i installed?

Comment: Sorry, that was my SmartPhone playing up on me. It should have been : implement or replace. The API is in a **JSR** and is well defined.

Comment: JSR has only specification but i need API of smartcardio.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot about that other Q/A, but you have your answer anyway I guess.